# How to tokenize natural English text in an input file in python?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to `tokenize input file in python` please suggest me i am new user of python .

I read the some thng about the regular expression but still some confusion so please suggest any link or code overview for the same.

Comment: What do you want to tokenize? Do you need to create a generic tokenizer? Or do you need a tokenizer/parser for a specific (programming) language?

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this:

```
import nltk
file_content = open("myfile.txt").read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(file_content)
print tokens
```

The NLTK tutorial is also full of easy to follow examples: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html

Comment: He OP may not want to tokenize a natural text, but source code for a formal language. nltk is for parsing natural languages. For formal languages, you can use ply. I use it extensively for building custom compilers.

http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

With ply you can also parse and compile into an abstract syntax tree.

Comment: @nagylzs - The question is tagged "nltk".

Answer (score 4):

## Using `NLTK`

If your file is small:

- Open the file with the context manager `with open(...) as x`,
- then do a `.read()` and tokenize it with `word_tokenize()`

[code]:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
with open ('myfile.txt') as fin:
    tokens = word_tokenize(fin.read())
```

If your file is larger:

- Open the file with the context manager `with open(...) as x`,
- read the file line by line with a for-loop
- tokenize the line with `word_tokenize()`
- output to your desired format (with the write flag set)

[code]:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
with open ('myfile.txt') as fin, open('tokens.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        tokens = word_tokenize(line)
        print(' '.join(tokens), end='\n', file=fout)
```

---

## Using SpaCy

```
from __future__ import print_function
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)

with open ('myfile.txt') as fin, open('tokens.txt') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(line)
        print(' '.join(tokens), end='\n', file=fout)
```