# How to tokenize big files in NLTK library

Tags: python, nltk, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to tokenize this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o6kUrJxgINa_aUaxiDM8VJwT7hoZSOUw/view?usp=sharing) with 32 MB of size. I'm trying to do this with Google Colab and Visual Code. It worked with a smaller file, but I would like to know how to do it with a bigger file in a feasible way (it's been passing more than 1 hour).

My code in google Colab:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk import word_tokenize
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/drive')

raw = open('../drive/MyDrive/NLTK/data.txt').read()

tokens = word_tokenize(raw)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you could try looping line by line like mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511849/12702651

Answer (score 0):

You are reading and passing the entire file as a string, it’s not the nltk‘s fault. In fact the nltk has hidden support for incremental reads, so you should be able to work with iterators.

Use a PlaintextCorpusReader to read your data, then retrieve it incrementally by looping over `mycorpus.words()`. This way you could even retrieve sentences (with `sents()`), which do go across multiple lines. Do not try to collect a list of all the tokens, unless you really need that. That should do the right thing.